# Good or bad Idea to change magento 2 core files?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-core, core-hacks

Why is it not recommended to modify the Magento 2 core files?

I'm guessing that when Magento 2 updates it replaces those modified files with the new files so it would be a best practice to create a extension/plugin instead?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking or telling? It is always recommended not to modify any framework's core files directly, otherwise you will not be able to update i future.

Comment: somewhere i heard, if anyone modified core files, they will go to hell :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitively, in any framework it is a bad idea to modify core files. There is almost always some way to override native code. There are many reasons, the two main being:

- The risk to create side-effects on other modules
- The risk to see your modification wiped out when you update the framework

Regards